# Linux Mint - Cannot get Canon MF4370dn scanner to work

Tags: linux-mint, scanner, sane, canon

So i have linux mint 18.1 installed and i have a Canon MF 4370dn printer/scanner, i got the printer side working using the drivers from Canon's site, but the scanner side is still not working.

`scanimage -L` recognizes the scanner:

```
device `pixma:04A926EC_SJF890301025D' is a CANON Canon imageCLASS MF4360 multi-function peripheral
```

`scanimage -V`:

```
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.25git; backend version 1.0.25
```

`scanimage -T` fails:

```
$ sudo scanimage -T
scanimage: scanning image of size 640x877 pixels at 24 bits/pixel
scanimage: acquiring RGB frame, 8 bits/sample
scanimage: reading one scanline, 1920 bytes...  FAIL Error: Error during device I/O
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Canon MF4370dn's specifications page](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/imageclass-mf4370dn) shows:

> OS Compatibility
>   Windows® 7, Windows Server® 2008, Windows Vista®, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP/2000, Mac® OS X 10.3.9 & up, Linux (**print only**)

Comment: Ok.... Could i run the scanner in a vm or with wine?

Comment: Although the printer is listed as a sane compatible device: http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html

Comment: I really need the scanner to work...

Answer (score 2):

This scanner works over USB out of box with xsane 0.999 on mint 18.1.  I am transitioning from openSuse 13.1 where it also worked, just tried it on 18.1.

I don't remember the network scanning working tho.

And I'm certain it would work in a VM (although haven't tried).

HTH